# redirect_uri_missing error is displayed when trying to authenticate in box-api in android

Tags: android, box-api

I am trying to run the SampleOAuth demo i have entered the client_id and clientSecret in the OAuthSampleApplication class. I am getting the error "redirect_uri_missing " when the app is trying to authenticate.

I got the sample with box-android-sdk-v2-master which i downloaded from git-hub. Can anyone tell me what is causing this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the loopback address to the redirect_uri?

If not, click on edit application and type the loopback address.

Scroll down and Save the application.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have one question what will happen when we enter the URL as android does not have web server running to redirect the URL.